# Use Excel Formula to find total number of sales of specific product

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am using Excel Formulas to count the total sales of a Product. On a Data Sheet it needs to find each position of the Product and sum the number of sales.

I have used VLOOKUP to find and get one number of sales but it only takes the first sale. I tried to use COUNTIF but that didnt work.

```
   =VLOOKUP(J1;A:E;5;FALSE)
   =COUNTIF(A:A;3021;E:E;3021)
```

The Result i get is 6. What i expect is 6 + 10 + -4 = 12.
The Sales can also be negative -2 
Screenshot to reproduce Problem:

[image: Spreadsheet to Reproduce Problem]

Comment: Try SUMIF instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use productsum which can sum the way you want.

You need to remember to enclose the arguments in own `()` and multiply them (dont use `,`)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=J1)*(E1:E10))
```

[image]

The good thing with Sumproduct is that you can expand it easily to get the total sale sum (column B).

[image]

(5*6+2*10+1*-4 = 46)

Comment: Thanks alot for the help i wasnt familiar with sumproduct yet!